# angular refresh select options

Tags: angular, select, refresh

i want to refresh the select B options once select A change
how can i made this?

```
//select A
<select (change)="fasechange()" name="" [(ngModel)]="fase" id="">
   <option *ngFor="let item of arrayA">{{item.name}}</option>
</select>

//Select B
<select name="" [(ngModel)]="equipo1"  id="">
    <option *ngFor="let item of arrayB">{{item}}</option>
</select>
```

and in the change function for select A

```
arrayB: Array<string> = [];
fasechange(){
  for(let a of this.options){
    if(a.name == this.fase){
      this.arrayB.push(this.option.opt);
    }
  }
}
```

i ned to update, refresh the select B onnce the change function ends, how can i make this happen???
thanks for the help

Answer (score 0):

After Push, you need to create new reference for arrayB.

```js
fasechange(){
  for(let a of this.options){
      if(a.name == this.fase){
          this.arrayB.push(this.option.opt);
          this.arrayB  = [...this.arrayB]
      }
   }
}
```

Comment: nop the select b still dosnt update its options

Comment: can you share stackblitz for same.

Answer (score 0):

You could also use [ChangeDetectorRef](https://angular.io/api/core/ChangeDetectorRef) to force the update.

```
fasechange(){
  for(let a of this.options){
    if(a.name == this.fase){
      this.arrayB.push(this.option.opt);
      this.changeDetector.detectChanges(); // Inject it in your component constructor
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

After push you need to recreate the array reference (as mentioned in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/72167057/3045105)) but since you have array of objects, you need to clone the objects as well.

So the code would be something like this:

```js
this.arrayB = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(this.arrayB));
```

or with lodash (or any other utility library with deep cloning:

```js
this.arrayB = _.cloneDeep(this.arrayB);
```